# Find unused using statements with MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, refactoring, monodevelop, using, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to write an addin for detecting unused using statements in my C# solution. With `MonoDevelop.Ide` I can access *all* using statements of the current document with

```
var document = IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument.ParsedDocument
foreach (var u in (document.ParsedFile as CSharpUnresolvedFile).RootUsingScope.Usings)
    Console.WriteLine(u);
```

This outputs something like

```
System.Collections.Generic
System.Linq
Foundation
...
```

The Immediate console tells me, `u` is

```
{Foundation}
    Identifier: "Foundation"
    LookupMode: ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.NameLookupMode.TypeInUsingDeclaration
    TypeArguments: {ICSharpCode.NRefactory.EmptyList<ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.ITypeReference>}
    Non-public members:
```

But how to tell whether, e.g., `Foundation` is used somewhere within the document?

(Due to the gray syntax highlighting in my IDE, I assume it's possible at all.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a facility that is already implemented in MonoDevelop. To enable it, you need to go to Preferences -> Text Editor -> Source Analysis, and check the option "Enable source analysis of open files".

Comment: Yes, then I can right-click and "Remove redundant using directives". But I'm trying to do it programmatically. At the end of the day I want to walk through all files and remove those unused usings. (As far as I know this is built in Visual Studio, but not in Xamarin Studio, which I'm using.)

Comment: interesting, then what you basically want to do is implement this feature request which I filed some time ago: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15203 . With this, I encourage you to implement it as a MonoDevelop feature, not as a new add-in. Also because you should reuse the code that there is already for removing the "using" statements, not reinvent the wheel.